# Changing contents of files through shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a requirement where I need to change the contents of a file say file.xyt. The file contains values like:

```
21 100 34 82
122 50 75 12
88 10 15 45
```

I need to see if the fourth argument in every line (which for this example are 82, 12, and 45) is less than 23.
And if so, i need to delete that specific line.

For this example, the result will be:

```
21 100 34 82
88 10 15 45
```

How can i achieve this using shell script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there always 4 fields in each line?

Comment: You should show your code. As it stands, it looks like a "give me the code" question. You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '$4 >= 23 {print}' file
```

that can be shortened to(thanks @RomanPerekhrest):

```
awk '$4 >= 23' file
```

If you want to write the file in place, you can use a temporary file:

```
awk '$4 >= 23' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

In case you have `gawk` 4.1.0 or later, you can use the `-i` flag to edit the file *in place*:

```
gawk -i '$4 >= 23' file
```

Or using a Bash loop:

```
while read -r a b c d; do
  [[ $d -ge 23 ]] && echo $a $b $c $d
done < file
```

Comment: Or shorthand `awk '$4 >= 23 1' file.txt`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, no need of that `1`, just `awk '$4>=23' file`

Comment: That's even better `:)`

Comment: The `awk '$4 >= 23' file` code is great! But it only print out the result in terminal and did not change the content of file.xyt. I tried to use `awk '$4 >= 23' file.xyt > file.xyt` but all it does is just make file.xyt as an empty file. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, i use `awk '$4 >= 23' file.xyt | tee file.xyt` and it does what i wanted. Thanks a lot for all your kind responses :)

Comment: I added some alternatives for editing the file in place.

Comment: @SLePort Thanks, that was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

In case if each line of the file contains 4 separate numbers, to modify the initial file in place you may use the following ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -Ei '/\<(1{,1}[0-9]|2[0-2])$/d' file.xyt
```

---

`file.xyt` contents:

```
21 100 34 82
88 10 15 45
```